# i want to make a click and reveal on my 4 text pads

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am a begginer and i really want to make a click or hold cursor on the each pad separately and reveal the text inside:
thisis the code:

```
`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>ProiectIA1</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        <h2 class="heading--text">PROIECT=IA1</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="eu">
      <img src="eu.jpg" alt="eu">
    </div>



    <section class="text-pad-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="text-pad1">
          <p>This is text pad 1. You can replace this text with your own content.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="text-pad2">
          <p>This is text pad 2. You can replace this text with your own content.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="text-pad3">
          <p>This is text pad 3. You can replace this text with your own content.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="text-pad4">
          <p>This is text pad 4. You can replace this text with your own content.</p>
        </div>
      


</div>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
`

CSS:
`

body{
background-image: url("fundal.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;


 height: 100vh; 
  overflow: hidden;
}



html {
  height: 100%; 

section{
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: left;
    min-height: 98vh;
    padding: 10px;


}
.box{
    display: inline;
    width: 80%;
}
.heading--text{
  display:inline;
  letter-spacing: 15px;
  height: 595px;
width: 37px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color:white;

font-size: 36px;
font-family:"Copperplate";
text-orientation: upright;
writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}

.eu img{
width: 415px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 51%;
    left: 7%;
    transform: translatey(-50%);
}


.main-container {
  display: flex;

}



.text-pad-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 40px; 

}

.text-pad1 {
  width: 70%;
  margin-right: 20%; 
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 115px;
  border: 5px solid #191970;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(30, 144, 255, 0.4);
position: relative;
left: 600px;
bottom: 785px;

}

.text-pad2 {
  width: 70%;
  margin-right: 20%; 
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 115px;
  border: 5px solid #191970;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(30, 144, 255, 0.4); 
position: relative;
left: 1120px;
bottom: 1115px;

}


.text-pad3 {
 width: 70%;
  margin-right: 20%; 
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 115px;
  border: 5px solid #191970;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(30, 144, 255, 0.4); 
position: relative;
left: 600px;
bottom: 1110px;}







.text-pad4 {
  width: 70%;
  margin-right: 20%; 
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 115px;
  border: 5px solid #191970;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(30, 144, 255, 0.4); 
position: relative;
left: 1120px;
bottom: 1437px;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

I need help with this s*it bcs i had my head around for 2 days and i can't figure it out.